# Visual Studio crashes every time I try to run Performance Analysis

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, profiling

I am new to profiling (never did it before) and I am trying to run a performance analysis on my project with Visual Studio.

When I start it, the program runs just fine but when I close the application and the performance starts showing the logs, the following error occurs and VS crashes:

[image: Visual studio crashing]

I tried opening the file with VS but the same error happens. Anyone know why it is not working?

Thanks.

Comment: having the same problem. did you manage to figure this out?

Comment: No, it fixed itself after a while, don't remember what I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it helps anyone else

I had this problem and it went away after I installed VS 2010 service pack 1